# Robot Framework: How to make Wait until keyword from selenium library return true or false

Tags: selenium, wait, robotframework

I would like to Run a keyword if an element is present on page.

I try using Selenium library's  Wait Until Page Contains Element keyword, but it will always return "None", whether or not the element is present. I tried setting custom error, but that won't work either:

```
${condition} =     Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${locator}    timeout=5   error=false
Run Keyword if  '${condition}'=='false'       click element  ${some_refreshButton_locator}
```

Keyword click element  ${locator} will run only when I make condition '${condition}'=='None'

Am I doing something wrong and how can I make a Selenium Library Wait until... keyword return true or false.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Wait Until Page Contains Element* does not return anything but will raise error if element is not found. One workaround is to wrap *Run Keyword And Ignore Error* around it.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Test wait
    Open Browser        http://www.google.com/    gc
    ${result}    ${condition}=    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Wait Until Page Contains    Stackoverflow    timeout=2   error=false
    Run Keyword if  '${condition}'=='false'       Log    clicking
    Close All Browsers
```

Comment: Hi Pekka, this works great with elements that are not existing on the page, but my element is a check box in a tree view that is existing, but not visible. Using the above code snippet throws "ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with" How can I catch it and run a keyword when it is thrown?

Comment: Hi again Pekka, I am a newbie with Robot and still learning. TRied the very same concept with keyword "Wait Until Element is Visible" and now it works perfectly well for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

*"Run Keyword And Return Status"* can also be used to get True/False status as below:

```
${condition} =     Run keyword And Return Status    Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${locator}    timeout=5   error=false
```